# Owl Carousel 2 Sync Slider button not working properly

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I referenced this Codepen code for my website slider

[Owl Carousel 2 sync demo with loop/autoplay](https://codepen.io/oleg-z-zin/pen/JjdoqqL)

The next button in the first one is working properly

But the other button instead of sliding to the next or previous item it jumps to 1 or 5

Is there any other option I can use as reference?

I tried changing the code like in the reference said:

```
function syncPosition(el) {
//if you set loop to false, you have to restore this next line
var current = el.item.index;

//if you disable loop you have to comment this block
//var count = el.item.count-1;
//var current = Math.round(el.item.index - (el.item.count/2) - .5);

//if(current < 0) {
 // current = count;
//}
//if(current > count) {
  //current = 0;
//}

//end block

sync2
  .find(".owl-item")
  .removeClass("current")
  .eq(current)
  .addClass("current");
  var onscreen = sync2.find('.owl-item.active').length - 1;
  var start = sync2.find('.owl-item.active').first().index();
  var end = sync2.find('.owl-item.active').last().index();

  if (current > end) {
    sync2.data('owl.carousel').to(current, 100, true);
  }
  if (current < start) {
    sync2.data('owl.carousel').to(current - onscreen, 100, true);
  }
}
```

Newbie here. Sorry for the question.